# Static class or Singleton for utility class in .NET Core with DI

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton, static-classes

I'm migrating a utility class to a .NET Core class library.

At first I thought I can simply make a static class for this but I have a **dependency** on **IConfiguration** so I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

What is the best practice for this situation?

Should I use a **class** and use **constructor injection** and then add it in **ConfigureServices**?
Should I use a **static class** and use **method injection**?

Or I shouldn't even come across this type of issue :-?
I would guess that the first version is nicer.
Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm a bit confused for the options I have.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers. That said I would suggest you go the route of using a class with a backing abstraction, and apply constructor injection as common practice.

Comment: as I understand this is a utility class so it won't have any properties(Assumption) and if this contains only static method then making it class with constructor injection would be little over engineering as you also need to provide a way to register dependency. so I would go with second approach.